# Two Equal Functions, and their derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives

If we know that $f(x)=g(x), \forall x$, when can we say (or what functions exist), that $f'(x)=g'(x)$, or in other words, if two functions are equal, when is it possible to say that their derivative are equal? I was just wondering if such functions even exist (apart from both of them being the same)

Comment: Consider $f(x) = g(x) = x^2$.

Comment: I was wondering if functions that aren't the same (just equal in terms of their y value for $\forall x$

Comment: But then they are the same, just written differently. If the outputs of the functions are the same, then so are the functions

Answer (score 2):

Since the derivative is defined in terms of the function, this is obviously true.

Answer (score 0):

If two functions are identical for all x then their derivatives are equal, although not the same can be said in reverse - if two functions have the same derivatives, they are not neccesarily the same function : for example - $1/2(arctan(x))$ and $arctan(x-sqrt(x^2+1))$

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, the two functions you've listed are equal with a difference of a parameter (say $c$), since $f(x) = g(x)+c$?

Comment: Yep they are, and I just realised I could have done a simple example like x and x+1, but never mind

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that f(x)=g(x) for all x, then of course their derivatives are the same since their derivatives are defined in terms of the function themselves as Robert said.

However, if two functions have the same derivative, then they are not necessarily the same, e.g f(x)=x^2+1 and g(x)=x^2+2. That's why the integration constant comes in.